Firestore ConnectionState is "ConnectionState.waiting"
This appears to be an issue that has been answered before (e.g. by @MSaudi here). I followed that discussion but it did not solve the problem I am running into. Would appreciate some pointers as I am very much a beginner to flutter/firestore. I am simply following an online tutorial I found just to get myself acquainted with the basics. Its been going well up to this point.
Widget _buildUserList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _chatService.getUsersStream(), 
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // error
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text("Error");
        }

        // loading..
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text("Loading...");
        }

        // return list view
        return ListView (
          children: snapshot.data!
            .map<Widget>((userData) => _buildUserListItem(userData, context))
            .toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildUserListItem(Map<String, dynamic> userData, BuildContext context) {
    // display all users except current user

    return UserTile(
      text: userData["email"],
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatPage(
          receiverEmail: userData["email"],
          )));
      },
    );
  }



Something obvious I am missing maybe?
Adding code for getUsersStream as requested by @pskink
  Stream<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> getUsersStream() {
    return _firestore.collection("Users").snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        final user = doc.data();
        return user;
      }).toList();
    });
  }


post getUsersStream code

Have a look at this link

Please don't screenshots of code or other textual content, but rather post them as actual text and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark them up. Having the content as text makes it accessible, searchable and makes it easier for folks to help you. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

Thanks for replying guys I've added the code @pskink asked for. This is likely not a database connection issue because the user data is stored in the project, not in the database. I've been going over my settings files in firebase.json and firebase_options and nothing seems misplaced. Are there logs somewhere (either client or server) that would be helpful?

I/flutter ( 8396): AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null) - doesnt tell me a whole lot.
